# include CGAL library for only for certain subproject

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, cgal, cmake-gui

I am working on a subproject which is part of a whole framework.
The framework is configured with a CMakeList and each subproject has a subdir with its own sub-CMakeList.txt.

A want to add CGAL to my project but don't affect other projects.

If I add these lines to my sub-CMakeList.txt:

```
find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Core QUIET)
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
```

when compiling the project, VS always report cannot find the linked library.

(I dug a little and the reason is that ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} is not set correctly.)

But when I put these lines in the root CMakeList.txt, everything works fine, unless the system tries to link CGAL to every project.

Is there any method to:

1. Specific the target sub project for CGAL to link with?

OR

2. Make the **include** line work in the sub-CMakeList.txt?

**EDIT**

Let's make the question a little simpler:
I put the above code in the root CMakeList, and configure/generate. CMake gave me a lot of lines like:

```
WARNING: Target "KnitroLibCG" requests linking to directory "C:/Libraries/CGAL/4.11/build/bin".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

It seems many of my subprojects tries to link to CGAL, while I only need one of them do so.
How to specify a project for the link?

Comment: `find_package()` in a subproject should work (at least, until top-level uses the same package). Whether there is some output from `find_package` if you remove QUIET option? Show your other code with usage of CGAL, and show the error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev no. find_package() in a subproject doesn't generate correct ${CGAL_LIBRARIES}. removing QUIET got nothing new.

Comment: Hm, without QUIET there is normally a message about **where** the package has been found. Which script `FindCGAL.cmake` do you use? (Link would be sufficient).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I use. The ${CGAL_USE_FILE} is pointed to 
`C:/Libraries/CGAL/4.11/cmake/modules/UseCGAL.cmake` . Everything here is the official script, I never changed it. But removing QUIET doesn't generate anything new. The only issue is if I put in the subdirectory cmakelist, the linking mechanism is not correct, but if I put under the root one, it works.

Comment: `The only issue is if I put in the subdirectory cmakelist, the linking mechanism is not correct` - According to the warning you get when you put that into the top-level directory, linking is incorrect too: It tries to link with a *directory* instead of a **library**. Again, `find_package()` in subdirectory **should work**. It may be broken, if some other part of your code (or code from some other subproject) does wrong things. But without viewing the code it is difficult to diagnose the problem. **Try to debug**. E.g., comment out every other subporject, and check whether yours one works.